# What is on-topic here?

Tags: support, scope, cross-validated, open-data-se

I am trying to find the right site for a question and am a bit torn between `data science`, `cross validated`, and `open data`.

I was very surprised to find no guidance on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, only a few examples. Am I overlooking something? Where is the objective / about page here?

Answer (score 6):

Data Science and Cross Validated overlap. I'd say Cross Validated is more about statistics, math and theory, and Data Science is more about applied machine learning and data.

I'm a mod and I typically won't close a question that is on-topic here but also on-topic at Cross Validated. I'd only move it if it seemed much more on-topic there.

If in good faith you think it's on topic here, go ahead. People will migrate it if they really disagree, and that's no bad thing.

If you can help clarify the examples on the page you cite, let me know, I think I can edit it.

Comment: I can't presume to say what's on-topic at DS, but applied machine learning is very much on-topic at CV, & has been since the site's inception. [Machine learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) is our third most popular tag (while [neural networks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neural-networks) currently beats [mathematical statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-statistics)); & posts concern matters ranging from from the more theoretical to the more practical.

Comment: Much to do with data is on-topic at CV too - I'm afraid I didn't get what distinction you're making there.

Comment: It's questions about "the *implementation* of an algorithm, routine data processing, or details of the language", that do not "need "statistical expertise to understand or answer" (quoting from our help)  that are off-topic at CV - perhaps some of these are on-topic at DS though (many are at Stack Overflow).